# Searching mongodb _id field using regex

Tags: regex, mongodb

In my sandbox I have a collection, and the unique key (`_id`) for the collection is a unique string from another database. I have preallocated the documents and they look like this

The data looks like this

```
{ _id : "UNIQUEKEY1:1463670000000", data: {value:NaN} }
{ _id : "UNIQUEKEY2:1463670000000", data: {value:NaN} }
```

I would like to query the data in the following way

```
{ "_id": {$regex : "/^UNIQUEKEY1.*/i"} }
```

I have read that you can query `_id` if it is a string in Brendan's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612975/how-to-do-a-regex-query-on-mongodb-objectid-field)

I don't want the overhead of another attribute just to search by when the `_id` would provide me with enough

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3305687/244811?

Comment: Any reason you are nesting your values inside a data subdocument?

Comment: I am trying to preallocate the data so that it is contiguous on the storage.  Here is a good video that explains it. https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-time-series-data-part-2-analyzing-time-series-data-using-aggregation-framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a valid setup and $regex should work fine (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

So try `db.mycollection.find({ "_id": {$regex : /^UNIQUEKEY1.*/i} })` i.e. you shouldn't need the quote marks.

Comment: Are you saying this is working for _id in ObjectId type (which is the main point of this question)? Somehow it doesn't work on my _id of ObjectId type. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @newman - No this $regex works only on strings. In the original question, the `_id` is of type string not ObjectId which can be perfectly fine if your application ensures that it's unique.